# Im stuck in my pygame project, i dont know how to add sprites, scroll, and animated backgrounds

Tags: python, pygame

Context: Im trying to add something and i dont know, scroll, animated background and sprites.

And with the sound im confuse, other thing is that i dont know how to add time to my game, like for example a counter, or to add some time between an action in the game, i had working in this my project since last week, and stay stuck at this point, i search on google or anywhere and doesnt find what i want.

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *
import pickle
from os import path
from pygame import mixer
import time

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 512)

pygame.init()
mixer.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

ancho = 1000
alto = 1000
bg = pygame.image.load("img/Background/inicio.jpg")
segu = pygame.image.load("img/Iconos/juega.png")
salgan = pygame.image.load("img/Iconos/quit.png")
jugador = pygame.image.load(f"img/player/Idle/0.png")
pantalla = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho, alto))
icon = pygame.display.set_caption("You")
opciones = pygame.image.load("img/Iconos/pauson.png")
resumen = pygame.image.load("img/Iconos/restart.png")

pygame.mixer.music.load("snd/feel.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.1)
coin_fx = pygame.mixer.Sound("snd/coins.wav")
coin_fx.set_volume(0.5)
flip = pygame.mixer.Sound("snd/flip.wav")

# define font
font = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold", 104)
font_score = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold", 30)
# variables
money = 0
pressed = False
mantener = False
scroll = 0
pausa = False
pablo = False
def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    pantalla.blit(img, (x, y))
class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.clicked = False

    def draw(self):
        action = False
        # get mouse position
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # check mouseover and clicked conditions
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                action = True
                self.clicked = True
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False

        # draw button
        pantalla.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        # pygame.draw.rect(pantalla, (255, 255, 255), self.rect, 2)


        return action
class Pausa:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self):
        pantalla.blit(self.image, self.rect)
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self): # update se utiliza para la posicion del jugador y su movilidad
        dx = 0
        dy = 0
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            dx -= 5
            self.direction = -1
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            dx += 5
            self.direction = 1
        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            dy -= 5
        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            dy += 5
        if key[pygame.K_z]:
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0, 5000)
            draw_text("Tienes " + str(money) + " monedas", font_score, (0, 0, 0), 800, 10)
        # update player coordinates
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

    def draw(self):
        pantalla.blit(self.image, self.rect)
class Player2:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self): # update se utiliza para la posicion del jugador y su movilidad
        dx = 0
        dy = 0
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            dx -= 5
            self.direction = -1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            dx += 5
            self.direction = 1
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            dy -= 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            dy += 5
        if key[pygame.K_z]:
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0, 5000)
            draw_text("Tienes " + str(money) + " monedas", font_score, (0, 0, 0), 800, 10)
        # update rectangle position
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy
    def draw(self):
        pantalla.blit(self.image, self.rect)
jugador1 = Player(500, 500, jugador)
jugador2 = Player2(0, 0, jugador)
seguro = Button(500, 500, segu)
pausaoff = Pausa(0,0, opciones)
salir = Button(20, 420, salgan)
continuar = Button(20, 20, segu)
returno = Button(20, 300, resumen)
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    pantalla.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    if pablo == True:
        if seguro.draw():
            pass
            mantener = True
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0, 5000)

    if mantener == True:
        Player.draw(jugador1)
        Player.update(jugador1)
        Player2.draw(jugador2)
        Player2.update(jugador2)
        pablo = False
    if pausa == True:
        pausaoff.draw()
        mantener = False
        if salir.draw():
            flip.play()
            pass
        if returno.draw():
            flip.play()
            mantener = True
            pausa = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_v:
                money += 1
            if money >= 10:
                if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                    money -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                pausa = True
                flip.play()
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pausa = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_b:
                pablo = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pablo = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            pass

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with sprites, but scrolling and animated backgrounds are way out of my league. So I see you have loaded the images, and assuming you have no error images, in the while run loop, simply type this:
`pantalla.blit(sprite loading variable,(spriteX,SpriteY))`

pantalla is your screen, pantalla.blit() is needed to "blit" or put one image on top of another, `sprite loading variable` is something like `jagudor` because you wrote `pygame.image.load()`, then `SpriteX` and `SpriteY` are the x and y coordinates of the image. I recommend you start reading some pygame books because blitting an image is like the first thing you learn in pygame.